# Date, day, month and year increment by clicking next & previous button in Appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I need to change he date,day and month by clicking next and previous button in appcelerator. If i click on previous button date,day and month have to decrement and If i click on next button date,day and month have to increment. ANy help will be deeply appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer worked for me. Thanks.

```
 /**
  * Date,Day Change on left & right arrow click 
 */
        if (!Date.now) {
          Date.now = function() {
            return new Date().getTime();
          };
        }

        var theDate = Date.now();
        $.todayDateLabel.text = getTheDate(theDate);

        //****** leftArrow & rightArrow are Buttons *******
        $.leftArrow.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            theDate -= 86400000;
            $.todayDateLabel.text = getTheDate(theDate);
        });

        $.rightArrow.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            theDate += 86400000;
            $.todayDateLabel.text = getTheDate(theDate);
        });

    function getTheDate(getDate) {

      var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
      ];

      var months = ["January", "February", "March",
        "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
        "September", "October", "November", "December"
      ];

      var theCDate = new Date(getDate);

      return days[theCDate.getDay()] + ', ' + theCDate.getDate() + ' ' + months[theCDate.getMonth()] + ', ' + theCDate.getFullYear();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the moment js library:

```
var moment = require("moment");

var now = moment(); //today

now.add(1'days'); //tomorrow

now.subtract(1'days'); //yesterday
```

To get the date formatted:

```
now.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); //will return a string: 2016-05-25 11:01:32
```

MomentJS documentation:

http://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're asking to increment/decrement the date by 1 day each time

```
var date = new Date('2016', '04', '26');
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); //next day
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1); //previous day
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmvk82f5/

**Remember that javascript does months 0-11 instead of 1-12, so 0 is january**